# alignment with makecell

Tags: tables, makecell

Consider this example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{makecell}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
  A0 & \makecell{B01\\B02}\\
  A1 & Bbbbbbb1
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

I use `\makecell` in order to employ `\\` in a table cell.
The output is:

[image]

The alignment of `\makecell` is centred which is in dissonance with the lefthanded alignment of the cell below. Hot to make the alignment of `\makcell` lefthanded?

Comment: `\makecell[l]{B01\\B02}`

Comment: @Viesturs: You should read the [manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/makecell)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

p.3 of the manual

[image]

suggests

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{makecell}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
  A0 & \makecell[l]{B01\\B02}\\
  A1 & Bbbbbbb1
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]